# Unable to iterate list of beans in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying with the following code.

```
function linkClicked(list){
  alert(list.length);
  $.each(list, function(key, value) {
    alert(value);
  });
}
```

I am getting the `alert` and list length but I am not getting `alert(value);`. It means list not iterating.List contains beans that coming from controller.

This image shows list of objects:

[image: List of objects present]

Comment: Check console! What it says?

Comment: What is the value of `list`?

Comment: nothing is showing in console.

Comment: list length is showing as 512.list is showing as objects,but unable to iterate

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.
your list array display below type:

```
// OBJECTS
var obj = {
   one: 1,
   two: 2,
   three: 3,
   four: 4,
   five: 5
};
$.each(obj, function (index, value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: It is not array,it is the list coming from java controller

Answer (score 0):

The image you have attached shows you are getting your content as string and length of string is being shown first you need to convert it as list/array. then it will work.

```
function linkClicked(list){
  alert(list.length);
  var tempList=list.substring(1,list.length-1);
  var newList=tempList.split(',');

  $.each(newList, function(key, value) {
    alert(value);
  });
}
```

Like

```
linkClicked('[a,b,c,d]');
```

Comment: Yes I am getting objects displayed by doing this,but those are bean objects,when i am trying to display the attributes of that bean.It is showing as undefined.

Comment: I am getting alert as object

Comment: instead of simple alert try using 
alert(JSON.stringify(yourObject))

Comment: or try checking alert(yourObject.toString());

Comment: On doing so I am getting the same object with double quotes.                                                   "com.mkyong.common.dto.BillingServiceMappingDTO@cd7d0bc"

Comment: I want to get the value of value.product_type_id,value.product_cat_id,.. which are the attributes of DTO bean